# CSS image transform relative to parent size, and not image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a progress-bar using this image found on the internet:
[image: empty progress bar]
[image: full progress bar]

I want to use these to indicate level of skills on my personal CV-page, so I made an animation that loads the progressbar on hover to a certain point:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdeoYZ

Here's the problem: When I use a set value in pixels for `background-size` in `.overlay`, I get the effect I want: it looks as if the second image loaded from left to right.

But such progress bar isn't responsive. If I change `background-size` to `100% 46px` to fit the container, it stretches instead of "loading" from the left.

I have tried numerous variations, but is there a way to preserve exactly this effect, but make the progress bar responsive (fitting it's width only to parent size)? So that empty progress bar is always 100% of the container, but the filled progress bar is % of the empty progress bar?

The solution doesn't have to be in pure CSS, but I have next to no experience with JS and JQuery.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Oh, silly me, forgot to include the link; fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` sizes in the `background-size` refer to the elemet size not to the parent size. So if you shrink your element, the image will shrink with it.

You can use the css `background-size: cover;` to prevent the image from getting stretched. But you have to set the width/height of the elements to the right ratio in order to not clip parts of the images:

You can set this ratio dynamically by sizing the `.skill` element by `width: XX%` and for the height apply a `padding-bottom: YY%`. Since paddings are relative to parent `width` the aspect ratio will be preserved no matter how the container is sized.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}
.container2 {
  width: 400px;
}
.skill, .skill2, .skill3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom:9.1%;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/082lZ.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
.skill2 {
  height: 20px;
  padding-bottom:0;
}
.skill3 {
  height: 20px;
  padding-bottom:0;
}
.indicator{
  width:0%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  background: #0f0;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRR3g.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.skill:hover .indicator, .skill2:hover .indicator, .skill3:hover .indicator{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>good:</h3>
  <div class="skill">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <h3>good:</h3>
  <div class="skill">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h3>bad:</h3>
  <div class="skill2">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="skill3">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Keeping the ratio doesn't really work for me, though, as I want the progress bar to be fixed height along with some other elements on the page. I guess the solution would be to write a script that sets the pixel width according to browser window size…

Comment: see the edit: You can make the scale to the outer width preserving the aspect ratio by sizing the height of the element via a padding. All paddings reference the width of the parent element ;)

Comment: Oh, okay. But when I change to `width: 50%;` in `container2` and resize the window, progress bar's height changes as well, which is undesired; I wand fixed height and resizable width and preserving the visual effect, which is not the case when I test it :\

Comment: Then you should consider not using images for this, because if you only scale everything in on axis the image will be distorted. You could use `linear-gradient` to achieve a similar look using something like this: `background: linear-gradient(to right, #f00 0%, #d10 9%, #aaa 9%, #aaa 10%, #d10 10%, #0f0 100% );`. This will be scalable no matter what you do and will not distort ;)

Comment: Oh btw.. If you want to use window size you dont need a script. Use the css units: `100vw` (view width) and `100vh` (view height)